# Parsing multi-valued cells into crosstabs in R

Tags: r, crosstab, multivalue

I have a data set that, when imported as CSV, results in multi-valued cells for survey questions permitting multiple answers. Crosstabbing single valued answers in R is simple:

```
ctab(formula = col1 ~ col2, data = tmp) # given dataframe tmp
```

But I need to crosstab data as follows:

```
tmp2 <- data.frame ( 
  "level" = c ( "dir" ,    "mgr" ,         "dir",          "vp" ) ,
  "roles" = c  ("dev, qa", "dev, qa, ops", "dev, qa, ops", "dev")
 )
```

A naive ctab gives me this (& related):

```
                  level
roles          dir mgr vp
  dev            0   0  1
  dev, qa        1   0  0
  dev, qa, ops   1   1  0
```

But what I need is this (and I do *not* want to pre-specify dev, qa, ops, etc):

```
         dev     qa      ops
dir       2       2       1
mgr       1       1       1
vp        1       0       0
```

I did my best to search for similar. Apologies if this has already been answered. Thanks!

-ctb

Comment: What package are you running `ctab` from?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyr)
tmp2 <- data.frame (
"level" = c ( "dir" ,    "mgr" ,         "dir",          "vp" ) ,
"roles" = c  ("dev, qa", "dev, qa, ops", "dev, qa, ops", "dev")
)
tmp3 <- separate_rows(tmp2, roles)
table(tmp3$level, tmp3$roles)
#>      
#>       dev ops qa
#>   dir   2   1  2
#>   mgr   1   1  1
#>   vp    1   0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by first setting an index then splitting the string
The index is useful because it ensures against recycling.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmp2)
res <- tmp2[,index:=1:.N][,.(value=unlist(strsplit(roles,","))),.(index,level)]

##> res
##    index level value
## 1:     1   dir   dev
## 2:     1   dir    qa
## 3:     2   mgr   dev
## 4:     2   mgr    qa
## 5:     2   mgr   ops
## 6:     3   dir   dev
## 7:     3   dir    qa
## 8:     3   dir   ops
## 9:     4    vp   dev
```

be careful here as `strsplit` returns a list so you have to `unlist` the result for it to be formatted correctly.
Then we only have to dcast and we are done.

```
dcast(res,level~value,value.var="value")

##    level  ops  qa dev
## 1:   dir    1   2   2
## 2:   mgr    1   1   1
## 3:    vp    0   0   1
```